# Simple program to convert string to lower case and allow only letters don't work

Tags: c#, lowercase

can you guys tell me why this program don't change my input string into lower case string containing only letters? I mean only letter part does work but letters don't change to lower case. When I write YELLOW, I should see yellow in the window but I still ses YELLOW all upper case as the output.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
class czlowiek
{
    private string _imie;
    private string _nazwisko;
    private int _wiek;

    public string imie
    {
        get
        {
            return _imie;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(char.ToLower(value[i])) >= 97 &&     Convert.ToInt32(char.ToLower(value[i])) <= 122)
                    _imie += value[i];
            }
        }

    }

    public string nazwisko
    {
        get
        {
            return _nazwisko;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(char.ToLower(value[i])) >= 97 && Convert.ToInt32(char.ToLower(value[i])) <= 122)
                    _nazwisko += value[i];
            }

        }

    }
    public int wiek
    {
        get
        {
            if (_wiek < 0 || _wiek > 100)
                return 0;
            else
                return _wiek;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 100)
                Console.WriteLine("Wporwadzona wartość niepoprawna");
            else
                    _wiek = value;
        }
    }

}
}
```

and main program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        czlowiek admin = new czlowiek();

        Console.Write("Podaj swoje imie: ");
        admin.imie = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Cześć {0}!", admin.imie);

        Console.WriteLine("Podaj swój wiek: ");
        admin.wiek = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (admin.wiek != 0)
             Console.Write("Masz {0}", admin.wiek);


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because you convert to lowercase only in the `if` not in the assignment, there you use the original `value[i]`

Comment: Do you have an exercise where you cannot use some nice features like String.ToLower() or you don't know about it?

Comment: You can simplify the setter to: `set { _imie = string.Concat(value.Where(Char.IsLetter).Select(Char.ToLower)); }`

Comment: Yes, this is just an excercise to get the idea right. I'm just a hobbyist when it comes to C# but I really like it. When I changed 
 _imie += value[i] to _imie += char.ToLower(value[i]); it does work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set values like this:

```
_imie += char.ToLower(value[i]);
_nazwisko += char.ToLower(value[i]);
```

Comment: Mark as answer, it will be better )

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if I understand correctly. You want to "convert" string to lowercase and remove any character that is non alphabetical character ( "a-z" ) ?

If that's the case then you can use this piece of code :

```
public string imie
{
    get { ... }
    set {
        _imie = new string(value.Where(c => char.ToLower(c) >= 'a' && char.ToLower(c) <= 'z').Select(c => char.ToLower(c)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

This will get rid of all non alpha characters then cast all to lowercase and create a `string`.

[Check how it works](http://rextester.com/OIBO86726)

Comment: Yes, you got it right. It works really well this way, also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to process the input value for `imie` character by character, then your setter could be:

```
set
{
    _imie = new string(value.Where(char.IsLetter).Select(char.ToLower).ToArray());
}
```

Also,

```
admin.wiek = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

should be re-written to:

```
int numberValue;
admin.wiek = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberValue) ? numberValue : 0;
```

to avoid parsing problems with empty strings or strings containing non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet :

```
 string value = "HellO1234";
        IEnumerable<char> letters = value.Where(ch => char.IsLetter(ch));
        string letersString;
        string smallLetters;
        if(letters.Any())
        {
            letersString = new string( letters.ToArray());
            smallLetters = letersString.ToLower();
        }
```

Comment: You're aware that `ª` char with ( `170` ) code will return `True` used inside `char.IsLetter()` ?